# What's the best way to rank aggregate imdb rating data?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning, ranking

I have an [average rating of all votes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472954/epdate) as well as the total number of votes for all episodes of the TV show Always Sunny. Is it mathematically sound to?:

1) multiply each average rating by the total votes cast for that episode

2) take the array of all those values and normalize it so the lowest is 0 and the highest is 10

3) use that new value as the actual rating

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? You do want to rank a set of movies, right?

Comment: The previous question concerned discrete yes/no votes. This concerns a continuous 0-10 rating. To be perfectly clear, I don't want to actually "rank" anything. I just want to take into account the total number of votes somehow for each episode to produce a fairer rating. Like give 0-10 ratings with more votes more weight. I just used the term "rank aggregate" cause I thought that's what the official term for this is.